# Importing Large Terrain from Google Earth

Tags: google-maps, import, export, google-earth, terrain

I am currently using Google Sketchup 2015 Pro to export Google Earth terrain as obj wavefront format. I want to export Mount Everest and its nearby surrounding mountains so I can import it into a game. How can I do this?

I think Google Map Buddy did this, but it got banned, taken down, and it doesn't work anymore because people were downloading all of earth. Is there a better way?

If there isn't a better way to import larger areas on Google Maps, then I'll have to have tons of overlaying areas and I'll have to use the optimize tool in Cinema 4D to get rid of that.

Thanks

Comment: I also found [this](http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=323&t=40627) but I don't know how to use it and it still requires me to take tons of screenshots and edit out their overlapping parts.

Comment: [This](http://www.west-racing.com/mf/?page_id=2979) looks interesting. I will try it out.

Comment: So the terrain plugin for 3Ds max also has a limited space on it. I can take huge snapshots but it lowers the detail. I will try it though.

Comment: I also found [this](http://forums.cgarchitect.com/72359-large-scale-terrain-import-max.html) and it was useful but I didn't find what I was looking for. I want to import Mount Everest but it mainly imports North America.

Comment: Ok, so since no one is responding, I decided to use [this](http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm) and use 3DEM to export it as DEM and open and edit it in Cinema 4D. I think it comes from [this](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/) if you are wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USGS offers [a number of digital elevation models](http://eros.usgs.gov/elevation-products) (DEMs) at various resolutions with near global coverage which you can use as reference.

Amongst them, the [Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM)](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/SRTM) is the one at the highest resolution (~90 meters for the most part).

You can download GeoTIFF images of the areas of interest and then load them into [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/) to isolate the part of the DEM that you are interested in.

Once you have the DEM as a simple grayscale image, you can then use a program like [blender](http://www.blender.org/) to have the DEM [displace the vertices of a plane](http://johnflower.org/tutorial/make-mountains-blender-height-maps) surface and effectively convert the DEM to the surface of the mountain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is better because I can edit the area I want with something like Photoshop and then import it into something like Cinema 4D. I already decided to use a .hgt set of files which I converted with 3DEM but the way you recommended seems better for the next time I do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Skybase has released an alternative for Google Map Buddy, called Map Buddy - http://skybase.ca/mapbuddy/, but it is still a beta version, and requires several in-app purchases to get your work done.

It is worth a shot, though.